# Get category collection from product ID

Tags: magento2, category, collection

How can I get category collection data from product ID? I have tried using the following way but it's not working for me.

```
$product = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()->load($pid);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
if(count($cats) ){
    $firstCategoryId = $cats[0];
    $_category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->load($firstCategoryId);
    return $_category->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($pid);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
if(count($cats) ){
    $firstCategoryId = $cats[0];
    $_category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($firstCategoryId);
    return $_category->getName();
}
```

Comment: You should use the CategoryRepository to get an existent category (see post of Giel Berkers).

Comment: hi @Sohel, this code gives the category where product is not assigned.

Comment: You should use `getCategoryCollection` to request all categories one time, also, `getCategoryCollection` will cache result.

Answer (score 10):

Note that all above answers are not really the correct way to do it in Magento 2. Magento 2 introduced service contracts and data models as a new way to fetch this kind of data.

For example `$model->load()` is deprecated since 2.1, and collections ought to be replaced with repositories and it's uniform `getList()`-method that uses search criteria.

The Magento Way of fetching the categories according to a product ID would be:

```
// Get a product Data Model from the repository:
// productRepository -> \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

// Fetch the 'category_ids' attribute from the Data Model.
if ($categoryIds = $product->getCustomAttribute('category_ids')) {
    foreach ($categoryIds->getValue() as $categoryId) {
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this work with multiple store views? I am getting all store views categories when I want the ones for current store.

Comment: `Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface::get()` has a second parameter `$storeId` that you can use to get the category for a specific store.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, do you think you could show me an example? ->get($categoryId, $storeId); ?

Comment: How do you get a repository? I cannot find one for `Magento\Widget\Model\Widget\InstanceFactory`, for example.

Comment: Please add information about the classes which we need to inject in order to make it work. Otherwise your answer is useless.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to load the entire category which does too many sql queries.

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryAttributeRepositoryInterface $this->categoryAttributeRepository */
$nameAttribute = $this->categoryAttributeRepository->get('name');

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category $categoryResource */
$categoryResource = $this->categoryResourceFactory->create();
$value = $categoryResource->getAttributeRawValue(
    $categoryId,
    $nameAttribute,
    $this->storeManager->getStore()
);

// Additionally for other types of attributes (select, multiselect, ..)
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
$category->setCategoryId($categoryId);
$category->setData('name', $value);

// Final value as seen on frontend
$mixed = $nameAttribute->getFrontend()->getValue($category);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have using getCollection() to `$this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->load($firstCategoryId);` that `$_category`  **given a category collection instead of  single category object**

for your case,getting category name use  from *$_category* add  `getFirstItem();`

```
return   $_category->getFirstItem()->getName();
```

Comment: How to get category name with ordered item ?

Comment: is there any solution for this?